# How do I store if a CheckBox has been checked?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have an Activity that doesn't have to be displayed anymore if a "Don't show anymore" CheckBox is checked but I can't figure out how to make it work.

This is what I have tried up until now:

```
public class PopUpInfoActivity extends Activity {
static final String PREFS = "preference_file";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.popupinfo_layout);


    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dontshow_checkbox);
    chk.setChecked(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("value", false));

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //store isChecked to Preferences
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);

            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PopUpInfoActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("value", isChecked).apply();
        }
    });
}
```

This code still doesn't work because if I check the CheckBox and kill and restart the app, the activity still appears how can I make it work?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: where are you writing to sharedpreferences?

Comment: you need to write the preferences some when... otherwise is the logic incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for **setting checkBox value**

```
chk.setChecked(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("value", false));
```

use this for **getting checkBox value.**

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
          //store isChecked value in shareprefernce

          PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PopUpInfoActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("value", isChecked).commit();
       }
   }
);
```

enjoy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried it but I am getting an error in `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("value", isChecked).apply();` on `this` that says: incompatible types: <anonymous OnCheckedChangeListener> cannot be converted to Context

Comment: use `ClassName.this` instead of `this`

Comment: thanks that fixed it but another error appeared! `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference`. I will edit the code with what I have got now

Comment: first bind it like this  `CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dontshow_checkbox);` and then use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116874/discussion-between-daniele-and-sushildlh).

Comment: Please have a look a the question, this code still doesn't seem to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

you need to work with the preferences properly...

## Write it:

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putBoolean ("myChechButtonWasChecked", prefVal); //
editor.commit();
```

## Read it

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
bool storedPreference = preferences.getBoolean("myChechButtonWasChecked", false);
```