# How sharedPreferences store our data

Tags: android

After studying how to use sharePreferences to store values in activity, I still have some questions about the way it stores data.

Since after we hit back button to close our activity, Android usually will call `OnPause`, `OnStop` and `OnDestroy`. But in the way we use sharedPreferences, we call it inside OnPause method, like the code down below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor =mSharedPreferences.edit();

    String editTextString = mSharedPreferences.getString(EDIT_TEXT, "");
    mEditText.setText(editTextString);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mEditor.putString(EDIT_TEXT, mEditText.getText().toString());
    mEditor.apply();
}
```

In this case, I typed something and hit back button to back to exit the activity, when I go back to the activity. How android can still show what I typed in the EditText after activity got stopped and destroy.

Comment: have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282021/how-do-i-store-if-a-checkbox-has-been-checked/38282050#38282050

Comment: you are storing value with sharePreferences .. so after the destroy or stopped android still have store that value thats y..

Comment: You show it yourself `mEditText.setText(editTextString)`

Answer (score 0):

`onPause` always gets called when your activity ***loses focus***. Be it a switch to another app, switching the activity, switching off the phone or whatsover.

When you press the back button, `onPause` gets called and the value of the sharedpreference gets saved. After that, `onStop` and `onDestroy` [get called in the order written](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html). Next time when the activity is created, you are fetching the saved sharedpref value, so it'll show up.